# Can I make an opportunity attack as an armorer artificer and echo knight multiclass while wielding a 2H rifle BUT having Guardian Arcane armor on?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, artificer, echo-knight

So, I have this Armorer artificer Echo knight who is a ranged attacker. Opportunity Attacks only work with melee attacks. In case an opportunity attack is presented, can I just hold the rifle with one hand as a Free object interaction, and use the Thunder Gauntlet provided by the guardian armor to do a melee attack for the opportunity attack?

The gauntlet's rules say:

*"Thunder Gauntlets. **Each of the armor’s gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren’t holding anything in it**, and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on a hit. A creature hit by the gauntlet has disadvantage on attack rolls against targets other than you until the start of your next turn, as the armor magically emits a distracting pulse when the creature attacks someone else*".

So, if I released one hand, would they immediately count as a melee weapon, allowing me to make the Opportunity Attack?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the stack. I closed your question as a duplicate, because there is a very similar one, and the same logic should apply to your question. That is not a bad thing, and it should answer your question (hint: yes, you can). Let us know if that somehow does not solve your problem. You might also want to take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] center for additional help.

Comment: Cool, thank you!